# How to create ansible inventory from terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, ansible-inventory

I relay stack with that simple question.

Assume i need create few instance resources so how can i iterate from from tf variables to gather all private ips and pass it to ansible inventory file.

As i found i have to use * like here:

```
k8s_master_name = "${join("\n", azurerm_virtual_machine.k8s-master.*.name)}"
```

But i as think for me it will look like:

```
inst_ip = "${join("\n", ${aws_instance.*.private_ip})}"
```

But i got error:

```
Error: Invalid reference
 on crc.cloud.connect.tf line 72, in resource "local_file" "servers1":
 72:       inst_ip = "${join("\n", aws_instance.*.private_ip)}"
  
 A reference to a resource type must be followed by at least one attribute
 access, specifying the resource name.
```

Full tf file:

```
  resource "aws_instance" "sp-1" {
  ami               = "cmi-993E674A"
  instance_type     = "c5.large"
  monitoring        = true
  source_dest_check = false
  user_data         = file("user_data.sh")
  subnet_id              = "subnet-F6C45280"
  private_ip             = "172.31.16.18"
  vpc_security_group_ids = ["sg-230C7615"]
  key_name = "mmk-key"
  #network_interface {
  #  network_interface_id = "${aws_network_interface.ni-sp-1.id}"
  #  device_index         = 0
  #}
  tags = {
    desc = "sp-1"  
    group_name = "sp"
  }

}

  resource "aws_instance" "sp-2" {
  ami               = "cmi-993E674A"
  instance_type     = "c5.large"
  monitoring        = true
  source_dest_check = false
  user_data         = file("user_data.sh")
  subnet_id              = "subnet-F6C45280"
  private_ip             = "172.31.16.19"
  vpc_security_group_ids = ["sg-230C7615"]
  key_name = "mmk-key"
  tags = {
    desc = "sp-2"  
    group_name = "sp"

  }
}

resource "local_file" "servers1" {
  content = templatefile("${path.module}/templates/servers1.tpl",
    {
      inst_ip = "${join("\n", ${aws_instance.*.private_ip})}"
    }
  )
  filename = "../ansible/inventory/servers1"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Per the Terraform [documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions/references.html#resources), you need to reference the resource type and its associated name.

In your configuration file, you have an `aws_instance` resource with the name `sp-1`. If you wish to access the `private_ip` attribute of the resource, you need to do it like so: `aws_instance.sp-1[*].private_ip`.

Comment: Thank you for response. As i mentioned in question the instances are few ... update example ...

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a **single** instance `aws_instance.sp-1`, not multiple instances. To create multiple instance you would need to use [count](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/meta-arguments/count.html) or [for_each](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/meta-arguments/for_each.html), or provision instances through [aws_autoscaling_group](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/autoscaling_group).

Therefore, to access `private_ip` you don't really need splat `*` and `join` in your case (but still can use them if you want) as you have only one instance and will have only one `private_ip`. The following should be enough instead:

```
inst_ip = aws_instance.sp-1.private_ip
```

Comment: this just an example assume if i need more instance sp-1, sp-2 etc ...

Comment: and of course thank you for response. example updated.